# VBA put data from file to Excel Sheets

Tags: file, vba, io

I got file.txt structure like this:

```
"FIRST"
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 c2

"SECOND" 
e1 f1 
e2 f2

"THIRD" 
g1 h1
```

I got three sheets in my Excel file: "first", "second" and "third". How to populate this data into three sheets by VBA code?

Answer (score 3):

I still think that reading a text file line per line is the best way to go. 
You can load the entire file into an array and write conditions later.

```
Sub Read_text_File()

Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFS
Dim sText as String
Dim vArray
Dim lCnt as Long


Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\textfile.TXT")


Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
    lCnt = lCnt + 1 
    sText = oFS.ReadLine
    vArray(lCnt) = sText
Loop


End Sub
```

Then look through the array and do your stuff.

Or you could load the data in three separate arrays immediately, representing the three sheets.
This is entirely up to you.
Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Start recording a macro and open the txt file delimited by space. press ctrl + f and find First, Second and Third in three steps. copy your required range from the active workbook to your required workbook in respective sheets.

this will give you a recorded macro which you can restructure to make an automated code. Maybe i can post some code later. you will have to add lines of vba to read the line numbers of the cells used to find secon and third so that you know what range you have to copy.

1 question, number of columns in your file is as shown????

here is a code.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook


Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="D:\file.txt", Origin:=437, startRow:=1, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter _
    :=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other _
    :=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Cells.Find(What:="FIRST", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
startRow = ActiveCell.Row + 1

Cells.Find(What:="SECOND", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
endRow = ActiveCell.Row - 1

Range("A" & startRow & ":D" & endRow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

startRow = endRow + 2
wb.Activate

Cells.Find(What:="THIRD", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
endRow = ActiveCell.Row - 1

Range("A" & startRow & ":D" & endRow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wb.Activate
startRow = endRow + 2
endRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A" & startRow & ":D" & endRow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wb.Close (False)
End Sub
```